# How to use EmbedObject from Discord Webhook API

Tags: java

Well, im using the the https://gist.github.com/k3kdude/fba6f6b37594eae3d6f9475330733bdb API, but when i try to create a EmdedObject over my Mainclass, it willnot work, always a NullPointerException

So, i want to send a message to Discord over Webhook and i already tried just EmbedObject a; but it just says it cant be imported like that.

```
MainClass.java:

    public static DiscordWebhook dwh;
        dwh = new DiscordWebhook("https://canary.discordapp.com/api/webhooks/AAAAAA/AAAAAAA");
        dwh.setAvatarUrl("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/774033927476420608/ALqUMZi1_400x400.jpg");
        dwh.setUsername("LR-BotTest");

    public static void whenDone() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : botstatus.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey(); //RobotID
            String value = entry.getValue(); //State on/off
            System.out.println("1" + value + key);
            DiscordWebhook.EmbedObject a = null;
            a.setTitle("test");

            if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("online")) {
                dwh.addEmbed(a);
//              dwh.setContent("" + botowner.get(key) + " just went live with " + botnames.get(key) + " https://letsrobot.tv/robocaster/" + botowner.get(key) + "/robot/" + key);
                dwh.execute();
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }
            System.out.println("2" + value + key);
        }
    }

DiscordWebhook.java:
https://gist.github.com/k3kdude/fba6f6b37594eae3d6f9475330733bdb
```

With code which is shown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ReadJSON.whenDone(ReadJSON.java:61)
    at ReadJSON.main(ReadJSON.java:52)
```

Comment: `DiscordWebhook.EmbedObject a = null;` will not work, you need an instance to call `setTitle("test")`

Comment: @Lino u mean like just EmbedObject a? or how?

Comment: Maybe start with a java tutorial to learn about instances